# parse(value) throwing error when I have Image

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a text editor that stores edited value in a state called "value" like shown below.

I show preview of content added. The preview of the text looks like this when you do console.log

```
<p>This is the value intially</p>
```

So I'm using parse(value) to render content correctly.

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

 const [value, setValue] = useState('This is the value intially');

const getValue =()=>{
   return parse(value).props.children
}

    </div>



                    <Highlighter
    highlightClassName="YourHighlightClass"
    searchWords={["and", "or", "the"]}
    autoEscape={true}
    textToHighlight={getValue}
      

                    </div>
```

But when I add an image and click on preview, it crashes. Could someone help me?

Comment: This line doesn't make sense to me: `parse(value).props.children`. What is `parse()`? Are you sure `parse()` supports chaining as such?

Comment: So basically text editor gives me data with different p, h1, and h2. This parse ensures the data is rendered properly without tags. With just text, this code is working. Code breaks when there is an image. Is there an alternative instead of parse()?

Comment: Then it sounds like `parse()` is unable to process images. Without knowing where it is from and even so, it is a third party library, I'm not sure if there's much we can do

Comment: Edited code to show the parse import -->  import parse from 'html-react-parser';

Comment: So is there any way to automatically HTML like h1, h2, and p and show just the content? If there is a method to parse Image as well, I can move to that.

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`? https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml